# Firebase User Data and Application Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create an App that will save user typed information. Like stocks date and amount purchased. Will be personal user data, only the owner can read.
And a database that is common app data. Shared with all app users. This data will only be update by my self. The users will only read this. Something like when all market stocks paid dividends.

Firebase can handle with both situations simultaneously? 
What I have to search for get these solutions?

I tried to search on google and read the fire base documentation, I found for the first case but not sure for the second. And perhaps there is already a solution that addresses this scenario in a more simplified way than addressing two implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd model the use-case you describe as two nodes in the JSON of the database:

```
portfolios: {
  $uid: { 
    $pushkey: { stockid: ..., time: ..., etc: ... }
  }
},
stocks: {
  $stockid: {  
    $pushkey: { time: ..., dividend: ..., etc: ... }
  }
}
```

So the `portfolios` node contains information about the stocks that each user owns, using their UID as the main key. The `stock` node then contains the shared information about all stocks, that only you can enter/update.

To secure access to this structure, you'd use these [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "portfolios": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "stocks": {
      "$stockid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules allow the portfolio information of each user to be only read and written by that specific user themselves, while it allows the stocks to be read by anyone, but written by no ordinary users. You'd then use one of the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to access the database with administrative privileges to write the stock information yourself.

You'll need more JSON branches as you start building the app, but you'll likely secure all of them with a similar scheme.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I got the explanation and I will use It. Now I know that I can dig into this spending more time. :)